# If $A =[ 1/2 ,7/2]$ and $B = (1,9/2)$, show whether $A\cup B$ is compact or not.

Tags: compactness

If $A =[ 1/2 ,7/2]$ and $B = (1,9/2)$, show whether $A \cup B$ is compact or not.
Here $A$ is closed and $B$ is open set , but I not understand that whether $A \cup B$ is closed or open.

Comment: Can you write down $A\cup B$?

Comment: $ A \cup B = [1/2, 9/2) $

Comment: @Michel Burr ..Therefore AuB is not closed and not open ?

Comment: If AuB is not closed then it is not compact.